# rosjava missing library

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening,

I receive the following exception when trying to build rosjava:

/home/imre/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/node/RosoutLogger.java:59: package org.ros.message.rosgraph_msgs does not exist

Where can I download the package org.ros.message.rosgraph_msgs for rosjava?

I thank you in advance.

Here is my setup:

**OS:**

Ubuntu; Version 11.04 (natty); Kernel Linux 2.6.38-11-generic-pae; GNOME 2.32.1

**Version of ROS:**

At first, I had installed ROS Diamondback. And I had the error I am talking about in this question. Then I installed ROS Electric Emys in its place once it was released, but it was not due to my question. I still have the error with this version of ros.

**Version of java:**

java version "1.6.0_22"; OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1); OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

**Version of Ant:**

Apache Ant version 1.8.1 compiled on October 13 2010

**Exact commands used to download rosjava:**

At first I tried:
imre@TK-421:~$ svn co https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/

svn: Le serveur a envoyé une valeur inattendue (405 Method Not Allowed) en réponse à la requête OPTIONS pour 'https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg'

which means "The server has sent an unexpected value (405 Method Not Allowed) in answer to the request OPTIONS for 'https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg'"

So instead I used:
imre@TK-421:~$ wget -r -l 1000 --no-check-certificate  https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/

Imré

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11507/rosjava-missing-library/) by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are multiple problems:

1. You have to use ROS Electric, not Diamondback (should be resolved now)
2. https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/ is a Mercurial repository, not subversion, so you can't use svn or wget with it.  The correct command is:

   hg clone https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/ rosjava_core

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on 2011-10-20**:
This advice actually worked, thank you very much for your time and effort. I will post the complete answer.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-17**:
The last piece of advice I can offer is try to delete ~/.ros/rosjava and then "rosmake --threads=1 rosjava".  If that doesn't work, I can only think that the system setup is not configured correctly.

**Comment by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on 2011-10-17**:
I am indeed using ROS Electric now. I have also used the hg command. Now I can launch "rosmake rosjava_core". However, it fails with the  same error I sent this question for. It still misses the library I indicated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check whether you have a package ros_comm (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ros_comm). There is rosgraph_msgs in ros_comm.

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on 2011-10-17**:
Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question with the requested information.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-16**:
At this point there is clearly a configuration problem.  Please update your question to provide more detailed information about your setup, from what OS you are on, to what version of ROS you've installed, what version of Java + Ant you are using, and the exact commands use used to download rosjava

**Comment by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on 2011-10-13**:
I also updated ROS_PACKAGE_PATH after changing the name to "rosjava_core".

**Comment by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on 2011-10-13**:
I changed the name to "rosjava_core" and applied "rm -rf ~/.ros/rosjava". I still get the same error when runnin "rosmake rosjava". When I run "rosmake rosjava_core" the terminal freezes at "[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/imre/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111013-150638 ".

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-13**:
Yes, it matters

**Comment by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on 2011-10-13**:
Thank you for your answer. The error I got in the first place happens when I call "rosmake rosjava", that was why I posted my question. So, as I named my stack "rosjava" and not "rosjava_core", should I change the name I put or doesn't it matter?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-12**:
'rosjava_core' is the name of the stack.  When you checkout from source, you should name the checkout 'rosjava_core'.  If there are issues, try "rm -rf ~/.ros/rosjava" to make sure there isn't any bad state lingering about.   Also, 'rosmake rosjava' works as well.

**Comment by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on 2011-10-12**:
I thank you for your answer. So, if I understand well, the necessary jar will be created after I apply "rosmake rosjava_core". However, I don't have a "rosjava_core" package. I downloaded rosjava at the address that was provided to me: https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2011-10-12**:
org.ros.message.rosgraph_msgs must appear after command "rosmake" for package "rosjava_core". I have got "org.ros.rosjava.rosgraph_msgs-0.0.0.jar" in folder /home/alex/.ros/rosjava/lib

**Comment by [Imré](https://answers.ros.org/users/1204/imr%C3%A9/) on 2011-10-12**:
Thank you for your answer. I have the package ros_comm and rosgraph_msgs is inside but there are only py files in there. I am looking for the java library, which contains the rosgraph_msgs.java class.